# ORACLE EXPLAIN PLAN, valores errados?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Estou usando o `explain plan` do `Oracle` para levantar algumas estatísticas e está acontecendo o seguinte problema:

Quando criei o banco, criei uma tabela X com 50 inserts. Logo depois, inseri cerca de mais 2000 inserts na mesma tabela X, e agora quando uso o explain para por exemplo:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM X;
```

O explain percorre as 2000 linhas, mostrando-as na tela, mas mostra a quantidade de linhas percorridas antigas na tabela do explain. Ele percorre 2000 linhas mas coluna "ROWS" do explain mostra 50 (a quantidade antiga de inserts).

Alguém pode me explicar o por que disso estar acontecendo e como arrumar?

Comment: Veja se ajuda http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/stats.htm#g49431

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É importante perceber que o número 50 representa a estimativa que o optimizador calculou com base nas estatísticas que possui no momento da execução.

Antes de mais podes tentar, se estiveres com uma versão igual ou superior a 10g, executar o seguinte:

```
SELECT /*+ GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS */ *
FROM   X
```

Esta opção (pista/hint) diz ao Oracle para recolher estatísticas de execução para uma determinada instrução SQL. Caso estejas a usar a função

`(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(FORMAT=>'ALLSTATS LAST'))`

estes resultados serão depois apresentados lado a lado com as estatísticas que o optimizador estimou no execution plan.

As estatísticas originais estimadas pelo optimizador são mostradas na coluna E-Rows enquanto as estatísticas actuais capturadas durante a execução são mostradas na coluna A-Rows. Por exemplo como na imagem em baixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Diferenças nos resultados podem ser explicadas, em minha experiência, pelo seguinte:

- **Estatísticas desactualizadas** no momento em que estar a correr o EXPLAIN PLAN. A versão [11g](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:1133388300346992024) trouxe melhorias relativas à actualização e recolha automática de estatísticas. 
  Caso não estejas com esta versão e vejas que as estatísticas não são actualizadas quando existem alterações substanciais dos dados da tabela (TRUNCATE, BULK INSERT, ...) podes sempre actualizar as estatísticas manualmente e depois voltar a analisar os resultados:

  > EXEC
  >   dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('EsquemaBaseDados','X',cascade=>TRUE);
- Outra razão pode ter a ver com o **próprio conteúdo da tabela**. Imagina o caso seguinte:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM   X 
    WHERE  Y = 'ABC'
```

A tabela X poderia ter 2000 registos mas em que existem apenas cerca de 40 valores distintos para a coluna Y. Neste caso 2000/40 = 50 e o optimizador poderia estimar que uma habitual consulta por Y iria devolver 50 registos. 
Com isto quero apenas dizer que, por vezes, as particularidades dos dados influenciam as estatísticas.

Podes sempre, caso o julgues necessário, recorrer a um histograma para melhorar as tuas estatísticas. Mas, como tudo relacionado com Oracle, em caso de dúvida [pergunta ao Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:707586567563)

Como comentário final diria apenas que, ainda que a estimativa não esteja correcta isto não representa necessariamente um problema. Se uma query estiver a utilizar um execution plan relativamente actualizado com boa performance então não deve haver problema. Agora se as estatísticas estiverem completamente ao lado então aí sim, pode significar que não está tão optimizado quanto deveria.

Comment: já tinha a resposta mas mesmo assim muito bom! parabéns e obrigado!